# how to distribute an app in appexchange?

Tags: appexchange, app

I've created a bulk sms app on force.com 
How can Distribute the app into the AppExchange? and any people could access and download it for their use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have an app available on the AppExchange, you'll need to register as an ISV (Independent Software Vendor) through Salesforce's partner program, and have your app pass a security review.

That's about the limit of my knowledge on that particular topic.

The site to go to to start the process is https://partners.salesforce.com

Comment: clear answer 
thank you Derek